# How can i automate my post requests in nodeJS API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJS for my API. I have user table.On my frontend i have signup and login forms, and page where i am displaying in table all of the users.

For the performance i builded pagination on my api, so every page has 20 users for showing clicking on page2 on the table on the frontend will show the next 20 etc. Now to test my pagination i need a lot of users in my table.

It is booring to make http post request from my frontend or from postman 40+ times to test my backend API.

I know that i can make one page to show one users - so with 5 post requests it can be tested - with that i will have 5 pages.  But i wonder how can i do this process automatically - post as many request as i want through my nodejs api ?

For example the post request body looks like this

```
{
    "email": "test@hotmail.com",
    "first_name": "sdsd",
    "last_name": "sdsdsd",
    "password": "11111111",
    "confirmPassword": "11111111"
}
```

The values from the properties don't need to be different.Their uuid will be different which is handled on the api.

How can i make 40 post request automatically on `http://localhost:3000/v1/api/user/register`
for example ?

Comment: Try a `for` loop.

Comment: This question is quite broad - there are a whole host of things you could do to automate this process. If you're using nodejs, consider writing a script that utilises the [request library](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: @jonny — The request library is deprecated and shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: You can seed your database with dummy users. Check [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) and `database seeding` term